# Find the occurrence of a word in a string, and print it along with the next 4 characters C#

Tags: c#, substring

I have a problem with this string = " Leeds United 1  Chelsea 0, Arsenal 1  Leeds United 1, Leeds United 3  Fulham 1, Liverpool 2  Leeds United 1, Swansea 2  Leeds United 4"

I want to be able to take each occurrence of the words "Leeds United" plus the score next to it and just print those scores out. I've tried using substrings, but Im unsure how to code it to make it go 4-5 places along as well

Comment: Post what code you have tried so far and why it didn't work.

Comment: Side note (off-topic): The string is a little unrealistic, it isn't very likely Leeds can beat all of those teams

Comment: Perhaps (one of) your problem(s) is that you can't phrase what you actually are trying to do clearly enough: "... and print it along with the next 4 characters" will give you strange results like this: `Leeds United 1 C`, `Leeds United 1, `Leeds United 3 F` and will just fail at the end of your sample string because there aren't 4 characters after 'leeds united'

Answer (score 3):

Question is not quite clear, but if you need to extract scores after `Leeds United` text - this can be easily done with regular expressions:

```
string source = "Leeds United 1 Chelsea 0, Arsenal 1 Leeds United 1, Leeds United 3 Fulham 1, Liverpool 2 Leeds United 1, Swansea 2 Leeds United 4";

var matches = Regex.Matches(source, @"Leeds United \d+");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Or, if you need score numbers only:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(source, @"Leeds United (\d+)"); 
foreach(Match match in matches) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); 
}
```

Comment: This is probably, what OP wants. And this is also one of the few cases, regex might actually be useful. :P

Answer (score 2):

You could use a LINQ query with some `String.Split`s:

```
var leedsScores = str.Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.Split(new[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Where(arr => arr.Length >= 2)
    .Where(arr => arr.Any(team => team.Contains("Leeds United")))
    .Select(arr => arr.First(team => team.Contains("Leeds United")).Split(' ').Last());

foreach (string leedsScore in leedsScores)
    Console.WriteLine(leedsScore);
```

prints out:

```
1
1
3
1
4
```

Comment: @MohammadMirMostafa: i have tested it with your sample string above. Here is the evidence: http://ideone.com/Y8JoW2

Answer (score 1):

Your question is *unclear* (provide the desired result); do you mean something like that (***Linq***):

```
String source = "Leeds United 1 Chelsea 0, Arsenal 1 Leeds United 1, Leeds United 3 Fulham 1, Liverpool 2 Leeds United 1, Swansea 2 Leeds United 4";

String result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, source
  .Split(',')
  .Where(line => line.Contains("Leeds United"))
  .Select(line => line.Trim()));
```

the `result` is

```
  Leeds United 1 Chelsea 0
  Arsenal 1 Leeds United 1
  Leeds United 3 Fulham 1
  Liverpool 2 Leeds United 1
  Swansea 2 Leeds United 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var totalResults = new List<string>();
        var s = " Leeds United 1 Chelsea 0, Arsenal 1 Leeds United 1, Leeds United 3 Fulham 1, Liverpool 2 Leeds United 1, Swansea 2 Leeds United 4";
        var sarr = s.Split(',');
        foreach (var i in sarr)
        {
            var substring = i.Substring(i.IndexOf("Leeds United"),14);
            totalResults.Add(substring);
        }
```

It will not work for games having higher scores than 9, but with Leeds United, I doubt there is any danger :P (Edited to inlcude "Leeds United")